# How can I make a method that receives an image as a parameter and changes its visibility to false in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a method that receives an image name from my windows form application, in order to change the visibility of the image to false but it marks an error

```
public void changeVisibility (Image img_name){img_name.visible =false;}
```

but I can't because of an error that says
"Image does not contain a definition for "visible" and no extension method "visible" accepting a first argument of type "Image" could be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`System.Drawing.Image` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx) represents the binary data that contains an image. It doesn't represent an instance where the image is displayed. So it's never visible or not visible.

If you're dealing with an image displayed in Windows Forms, perhaps the class you're looking for is [`System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx). It has a `Visible` property. (Case-sensitive - if you type `visible` you'll still get an error.)

You can also click on the control in the forms designer and the Properties section will tell you exactly what type it is.